intel core i7-1355u can I install 24.04 amd
I have Hp Envy 17.IT has intel iris graphics and NVDIA RTX 3050 dedicated. can I install the latest version ubuntu 24.04 iso?

This question is similar to: Will my device work with Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
